# Recommendation for MVC3 compatible report viewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, reportviewer

I have been using the Microsoft Report Viewer in MVC for some time and it is not stable, causing timeouts when exporting. I am wondering if anyone has had better luck with other products, or if there are any products made specifically for the MVC pattern at this point?

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Reporting is a very good package.

http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx

Can connect to OLAP cubes, SSRS and has report designer capabilities.

Comment: I cannot find anything on the Telerik site about using this with MVC?